# Sonarqube server can not be reached from Jenkins and Sonar Scanner

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am having hard time setting up Sonarqube to analyze projects. Every time I start Jenkins build or sonar scanner I am getting error message. 
The SonarQube URL, Database connection from Sonarqube seems okay. And, I had to downgrade to Sonarqube 5.6.6 from 6.0 because I had same issue hoping that downgrading would solve the problem. But issue is still the same.

When I execute this command from the project source: `mvn install -DskipTests=true sonar:sonar -Psonar`

I get following error message:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project kvms-shared: Unable to execute SonarQube:
>   Fail to get bootstrap index from server: connect timed out -> [Help 1]

And, when I execute `./sonar-scanner` from command line, I get the similar error message:

```
SonarQube Server [https://myexample.com] can not be reached
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 5.238s
INFO: Final Memory: 3M/115M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute SonarQube
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to download libraries from server
ERROR: Caused by: connect timed out
```

Comment: Can you connect to the sonar instance using a browser?

Comment: You seemed to be having a network etc. issue based on the "connect time out" given...

Comment: I can browse my sonarqube webpage (https://mysonarqubepage.com) with no issue but get the error message only when I execute sonar scanner or jenkins build. Also, when I execute sonar scanner and jenkins build using http://localhost:9000 instead of https://mysonarqubepage.com, I don't have any issue. Could it be https issue?

Comment: `connect timed out` is usually not a https issue. It can be a proxy issue. If you have a proxy server correctly configured in your browser, but are not using it when running maven, that may be the issue.